# D3 - Calling nested function invokes the parent function and result in repetition of charts

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to understand and implement the D3 reusable chart pattern.

[See sample implementation](https://bl.ocks.org/rcmoore38/9f2908455355c0589619).

Here the updatableChart is called after selecting the id '#updatableChart'.

Question 1:

If I want to adjust the height parameter by calling as below, in subsequent code, it duplicates the chart.

```
d3.select('#updatableChart')
    .call(updatableChart.height(450));
```

How should I use this pattern and update the height without affecting the original chart ?

Question 2:

Now if I need another chart, say, under div id '#updatableChart2', I can still call and get the chart using code below.

```
d3.select('#updatableChart2')
    .call(updatableChart)`
```

But when I try to adjust the height by simply saying `updatableChart.height(500);` it affects only the second chart. How can I be specific in choosing the chart instance to work on ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

The reason the chart is drawn again, is because I am calling the `updatableChart.height(450)` within a D3 selection. Instead it should have been called simply as `updatableChart.height(450)`, to adjust the height.

Answer 2:

The problem was that the same chart object is attached into different div elements.

If another chart is needed under a different div, then the original `barchart()` should have been instantiated into another copy, say `var updatableChart2 = barChart()`  and used further.